toggle maximize area problem. Grease pencil
 -
In new versions of grease pencil 4.1 the drawing mode becomes a cursor and i can't make toggle maximize area. I have to keep pointing my pen at the canvas to make a toggle ctrl space during working on a tablet. For example, in version 2.93 there is no such problem. you have to point the pen at the canvas.
